# Cloudinary upload works but can't retrieve the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cloudinary

I'm working with Ruby on Rails to develop an application and I'm really struggling with the following issue.

I have setup Cloudinary http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration and also Attachinary https://github.com/assembler/attachinary for users to upload a profile image using the rails application, I also want to be able to load these images in the Rails application to show the user's profile image.

I have setup the following code in the user.rb Model file

```
has_attachment :avatar, :accept => [:jpg, :png, :gif]
```

The edit page for User's comes under the Devise view in my application - edit.html.erb. The following form is what I'm using to upload User avatars/profile images:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
            <%= cl_image_upload_tag(:avatar) %>   
              <%= f.button :submit %>    
<% end %>
```

In the same View file I'm using the following code to retrieve the profile image:

```
 <div class="profile-image" align="center">
                <% if @user.avatar.present? %>
                <img src="<%= cloudinary_url(@user.avatar.path) %>" width="180px" height="180px" alt=""/>
                <% else %>
                     <img src="<%= asset_path "person.png" %>" width="180px" height="180px" alt=""/>
            <% end %>

            </div>
```

Upon the image being uploaded to Cloudinary it is given a random file name, for example: ecwc8x4ult960jzk8dp0

Am I uploading the image correctly and how do I retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

In the form try: `<%= user.attachinary_file_field :avatar %>`.

You should be able to retrieve them through the model like this: `<%= image_tag user.avatar.url if user.avatar? %>`, or like it's said in the Attachinary's documentation: `<%= cl_image_tag(@user.avatar.path, { size: '180x180', crop: :thumb, gravity: :face }) %>`. Omit the `<img>` tag and I suggest to not use inline css.

You could have 400 error for serving the images over HTTP instead of HTTPS. To fix that you should add `secure: true` to the cloudinary.yml or add `:secure => true` to the image tag.

I can't write comments... Are there any errors, could you post error logs?